# I am trying to convert my python files to exe using pyinstaller. how should i edit my spec file?

Tags: python, python-3.6, pyinstaller, py2exe

This is a spec file demo i found. Problem i am total amateur at this. i don't know what changes i need to make. I have two python scripts , from which one will be my executable and other i am using as a module, and also i have one json file.
this is the code i found

```
    # -*- mode: python -*-
a = Analysis(['..\\..\\bin\\kano-burner'],
             pathex=['C:\\Kano\\kano-burners'],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=None,
             runtime_hooks=None)


import os
import glob

def extra_datas(path):
    def recursive_glob(path, files):
        for file_path in glob.glob(path):
            if os.path.isfile(file_path):
                files.append(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), file_path))
            recursive_glob('{}/*'.format(file_path), files)

    files = []
    extra_datas = []

    if os.path.isfile(path):
        files.append(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), path))
    else:
        recursive_glob('{}/*'.format(path), files)

    for f in files:
        extra_datas.append((f.split('kano-burners')[1][1:], f, 'DATA'))
    return extra_datas

a.datas += extra_datas(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), '..', '..', 'res'))
a.datas += extra_datas(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), '..', '..', 'win'))
a.datas += extra_datas(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), '..', '..', 'DISCLAIMER'))


pyz = PYZ(a.pure)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          name='Kano Burner.exe',
          debug=False,
          strip=None,
          upx=True,
          console=False , icon='..\\..\\res\\icon\\burner_icon.ico')
```

Answer (score 1):

For your simple case you should be good using the pyinstaller command line directly.

```
pyinstaller --onefile main.py childModule.py
```

And any additional files can be added using

```
--add-data
```

Option.

Comment: I used `pyinstaller --onefile main.py childmodule.py --add-data file.json` , but it is showing "invalid add_data _or_binary value" error.

Comment: Beside the error for data files the main problem is; as soon as i click on the exe file, it opens, and shuts down before i can see anything.

Comment: Hi. Please provide more information on what platform you're trying to create the installer.

Comment: its for windows obviously. and i am using mac currently but i also tried on windows platform it was not happing the app was getting the moment i try to open it.